# After adding foreach the page is getting blank

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am adding the `foreach()` and ending it as `endforeach()`, then the whole section within the `foreach()` goes blank.

```
<?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>  
<div class="profile_head" 
style="background-image: url(<?= base_url() ?>/assets/img/<?= $article->cover_image ?>)">  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am using **codeigniter** to do my project and the above code is written in the view page.

Comment: </div> close the div

Comment: add this echo "<pre>";print_r($articles ); before foreach to check weather $articles array is empty or not.. I think its empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
<?php foreach($articles as $article) { ?>  

<div class="profile_head" style='background-image: url("<?php echo base_url('assets/img/'. $article->cover_image);?>")'>  
</div>

<?php }?>
```

Make sure you set the base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

If on live domain put your domain url in.

End base url above with a forward slash `/` so saves you have to put in code before `/assets`

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I reviewed the

`<div class="profile_head" style="background-image: url(<?= base_url() ?>/assets/img/<?= $article->cover_image ?>)">` some times.and I could not find the end `</div>`tag.

So,you should add `</div>` at that sentence's tail.

Comment: yes, I have added it but still it is not showing anything it is bank.

Comment: and you can use `print`,`var_dump` to check the 'articles ' array whether it is not null, the base_url() is working at the right way?